# Exporting 2D graphics to DXF

Tags: export

I have a design that I've produced in Mathematica, consisting of two sets of `Rectangle` objects. The second set is a mirror image of the first and was produced with `array2 = Scale[#, -1, {0, 0}] & /@ array1`.

I'm experiencing two issues when I `Export` the `Graphics` object to DXF:

1. The second set of `Rectangle`s doesn't get exported.
2. Each `Rectangle` gets exported as a pair of triangles.

Mathematica's `Graphics` output:
[image: Mathematica output]

What AutoCAD displays:
[image: AutoCAD display]

`Import`ing the DXF file back into Mathematica also shows that the bottom half is missing. I'm at a loss here - what am I doing wrong? Are either of these weird behaviours deliberate?

---

Edit: Here is a snippet of my code. It generates the design for a surface acoustic wave resonator. This consists of two transducers next to two gratings, each made up of metal strips, separated by a certain number of wavelengths.

```
l = 2; (* wavelength in \[Mu]m *)

d = 25.5; (* cavity length in wavelengths *)
(* NB this is the distance between the fronts of the transducers *)
vRatio = 1; (* how much faster the speed of sound is in the centre \
section *)

nTransducer = 25; (* number of finger pairs in the transducers *)
nGrating = 370; (* number of fingers in the grating *)
(* NB 2 fingers == 1 wavelength *)

fingerLength = 25; (* finger length in wavelengths *)
(* NB finger length is measured from inside edge of the bus-bar *)

SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
filePath = "2um.dxf";

fingersT = Table[
   Rectangle[
    {-(fingerLength/2 - 1/2) l, y},
    {(fingerLength/2 - 1/2) l, y + l/4}],
   {y, (d*vRatio/2) l, (d*vRatio/2 + nTransducer - 
       1/2) l, l/2}];

(* -- the rest of the transducer is produced in a similar way -- *)

transducer = 
  Join[fingersT, lSquaresTOut, rSquaresTOut, lSquaresTIn, 
    rSquaresTIn] ~Append~ lBarT ~Append~ rBarT;

(* -- a grating is produced above the transducer in the same fashion -- *)

(* This line originally read: array1 = transducer ~Join~ grating; *)
array1 = fingersT;
array2 = Scale[#, -1, {0, 0}] & /@ array1;

diagram = Graphics[array1 ~Join~ array2]
Export[filePath, diagram, "DXF"];
```

Comment: Apologies, the annotation should read 'Second array (inversion of first)'. Same thing really.

Comment: Exporting to a different format, such as JPG or SVG, seems to work correctly.

Comment: If you post the actual code used to generate and export then working on this will be so much easier. Otherwise, it´s just guesswork (which I consider a waste of time).

Comment: @YvesKlett. Sorry. I didn't want to post the whole thing because it's quite long and not terribly interesting - there are a lot of `Rectangle`s to generate. I'll update the question with an abbreviated version of what I have.

Comment: Excellent (please include the `Export` part) - what I can tell you right away is that polygons will be triangulated by `Export` as DXF.

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks for that information. Do you know why it exhibits this behaviour? Can it be changed? I'd much rather have rectangles than triangles in the exported data.

Comment: me too. I guess triangulation is the safe way for possibly non-planar or non-convex polygons - anyway, your code is still not working. Check it out in a fresh session, several variables are undefined yet.

Comment: @YvesKlett - Yes, I deliberately left off the code that generates a load of the `Rectangle`s because it would have made the snippet too long. If you change the line `array1 = transducer ~Join~ grating;` to `array1 = fingersT;` you should at least get something that works, even though it won't look quite like the image in the question. In particular, the exported file should still be missing half the output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7484/discussion-between-yves-klett-and-poorsod)

Comment: In Autocad Rectangle is formed by Closed Polyline and not filled. During the conversion some things may not fit. So, you can try in Mathematica to form Polygon filled instead of rectangle. That may map to Region or solid 2d in autocad. Don't know how it's been mapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smells like a bug to me (check e.g. `Export` to `PDF`, which works). `Scale` is only evaluated when rendered... anyway, this works for me (without changing the triangulation thing):

```
array1 = fingersT;
array2 = array1 /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, -y};
```

As for the triangulation, not much you can do in `DXF`. Perhaps use `PDF` or `EPS` and import that (or try other available `Export` vector formats. Or export `Line` primitives and convert those in AutoCAD to a polygon. Alternatively, roll your own DXF export, which may or may not be overkill.

**Edit**: Here is one homebrew-version of DXF export for those special occasions: [Export ContourPlot as DXF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54529/131).