# Export ContourPlot as DXF

Tags: export

I'm having some trouble exporting a ContourPlot as a .DXF (to be used in AutoCAD).

My code is:

```
LG3 = ContourPlot[1/2 - Sum[Sinc[(n \[Pi])/2] Cos[n (1 x + 4 ArcTan[y, x])], {n, 1, 200}] == 0.5,
  {x, -20, 20},
  {y, -20, 20},
  PlotPoints -> 100]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["LG3.dxf", LG3];
```

The relevant output is:

> Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the DXF format. >>

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DXF export is somewhat idiosyncratic (3D only) and slow. For the following I´ve reduced `PlotPoints` to make casual experimenting less glacial. The general idea is to extract all `Line` primitives and elevate coordinate tuples to 3D.

```
LG3 = ContourPlot[
   1/2 - Sum[Sinc[(n π)/2] Cos[n (1 x + 4 ArcTan[y, x])], {n, 1, 200}] ==
     0.5, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 20];

threed = Graphics3D[Cases[Normal[LG3[[1]]], _Line, Infinity] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, 0}]
Export["LG3.dxf", threed]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Whether this will agree with your further processing is another question, in Rhino3D this works well enough.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want 2D bells and whistles, you would have to roll your own DXF export (doable, but not necessarily pretty).

**Addendum (a.k.a not pretty):**

This is some really old (and quite probably astonishingly bad/embarassing code) that I have been using with good success for years and have not updated since its first working incarnation except for version caveats (talk about cruft). Use at your own risk. **Please feel free to update to a sleek new design**.

It takes a very limited set of 2D primitives (`Line`, `Circle` and `Point`) and returns a 2D DXF. One useful thing it does is to build blocks out of top-level list objects, which can be really useful when editing large groups of lines etc. For your example the export is much zippier than the inbuilt one.

```
ToN[number_, digits_: 8] := 
 PaddedForm[number // N, {20, digits}, NumberPadding -> {"", "0"}, 
  ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]

ToDXF[gobject_] := 
 Module[{header1, layers, startblocks, endblocks, startentities, 
   endentities, footer, rPOLYLINE, rARC, rCIRCLE, rPOINT, rBLOCK, g0, 
   blockobjects, insertobjects, rINSERT, entities, gexport, allowed},
  header1 = {"  999", 
    "Ugly DXF export from Mathematica by Yves Klett", "  0", "SECTION", "  2", "HEADER", "  9", "$ACADVER", 
    "  1", "AC1009",  "0", "ENDSEC"};
  layers = {"  0", "SECTION", "  2", "TABLES", "  0", "TABLE", "  2", 
    "LAYER", "  70", "1", "  0", "LAYER", "  2", "0", "  70", "64", 
    "  62", "8", "  0", "ENDTAB", "  0", "ENDSEC"};
  startblocks = {"  0", "SECTION", "  2", "BLOCKS"};
  endblocks = {"  8", "0", "  0", "ENDSEC"};
  startentities = {"  0", "SECTION", "  2", "ENTITIES"};
  endentities = {"  0", "ENDSEC"};
  footer = {"  0", "EOF", ""};
  rPOLYLINE = 
   Line[pts_] :> 
    ToString /@ 
     Flatten[{"  0", "POLYLINE", "  8", "0", " 66", "1", " 70", "0", 
       "  0", {"VERTEX", "  8", "0", "  10", ToN[#[[1]]] // ToString, 
          "  20", ToN[#[[2]]] // ToString, "  0"} & /@ pts, "SEQEND", 
       "  8", "0"}];
  rARC = Circle[m_, r_, {ϕ1_, ϕ2_}] :> {"  0", "ARC", "  8",
      "0", "  10", ToN[m[[1]]] // ToString, "  20", 
     ToN[m[[2]]] // ToString, "  30", "0", "  40", ToN[r] // ToString,
      "  50", ToN[ϕ1*180/π] // ToString, "51  ", 
     ToN[ϕ2*180/π] // ToString};
  rCIRCLE = 
   Circle[m_, r_] :> {"  0", "CIRCLE", "  8", "0", "  10", 
     ToN[m[[1]]] // ToString, "  20", ToN[m[[2]]] // ToString, "  30",
      "0", "  40", ToN[r] // ToString};
  rPOINT = 
   Point[{x_, y_}] :> {"  0", "POINT", "  8", "0", "  10", 
     ToN[x] // ToString, "  20", ToN[y] // ToString, "  30", "0"};
  rBLOCK = 
   objs_ :> {MapIndexed[{"  0", "BLOCK", "  2", 
        "obj" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], #1, "  0", "ENDBLK"} &, objs]};
  allowed = (Line[__] | Circle[__] | Point[__] | List[__]);
  g0 = Flatten /@ 
    If[Head[gobject] == Graphics, gobject[[1]], gobject, gobject];
  blockobjects = (DeleteCases[g0, Except[allowed], 2] /. rPOLYLINE /. 
        rARC /. rCIRCLE /. rPOINT) /. rBLOCK;
  insertobjects = 
   Select[ToString /@ (blockobjects // Flatten), 
    StringMatchQ[#1, "obj" ~~ ___] &];
  rINSERT = 
   objs_ :> 
    Map[{"  0", "INSERT", "  2", #, "  8", "0", "  10", "0", "  20", 
       "0"} &, objs];
  entities = insertobjects /. rINSERT;
  gexport = {header1, layers, startblocks, blockobjects, endblocks, 
     startentities, entities, endentities, footer} // Flatten;
  gexport
  ]

ExportToDXF[filename_, gobject_] := If[$VersionNumber < 6,
  Export[filename, ToDXF[gobject] // ColumnForm, "Text"],
  Export[filename, Riffle[ToDXF[gobject], "\n"] // StringJoin, "Text"]
  ]
```

Block usage (colors are not exported):

```
block1 = {Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 5], 
   Line[{{-5, -5}, {5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {5, -5}, {-5, -5}}]};
block2 = {Blue, Circle[{5, 0}, 5, {0, π}], Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}],
    Point[{-2, 0}]};

g = {block1, block2};

Graphics[g]
ExportToDXF["tst.dxf", g];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This Rhino screenshot shows the grouping of the primitives:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

As of **Version 10.4** this plot can be exported directly:

```
LG3 = ContourPlot[
 1/2 - Sum[Sinc[(n π)/2] Cos[n (1 x + 4 ArcTan[y, x])], {n, 1, 200}] ==
   0.5, {x, -20, 20}, {y, -20, 20}, PlotPoints -> 100];

Export["LG3.dxf", LG3] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.19185, "LG3.dxf"}
> ```

```
Import["LG3.dxf", "Graphics3D"]
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know that! It is still horribly slow,  though...