# Exported 2D geometry to dxf has units in inch instead of mm

Tags: export

I was able to export a simple graph (involute) to dxf, but I've got the dimensions in inch (for example, circle with diameter of 1 has 25.4mm in CAD). I tried to use  `Scale` but I get an error. Is there a simple way around to get this done?

```
db = 1;
aa = 1.7;
r = db/2; 
circle = ParametricPlot[r {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}][[1]];
inv = {ParametricPlot[
       r {(Sin[w] - w Cos[w]), (Cos[w] + w Sin[w])}, {w, aa, 0}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.2]}][[1]]};

Graphics[{inv, circle}, ImageSize -> {450, 400}, Axes -> True, 
          PlotRange -> Automatic]  

involute = Graphics[{inv, circle}];

Export[importFileName = SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], 
       Scaled[involute, 1/25.4], "DXF"]
```

> Export::errelem: The Export element Graphics3D contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to DXF format. >>

Comment: Most dxf editors let you rescale the object

Comment: Most likely the inches are due to your import work flow. Often you can specify unit conversion  during import. Potentially related /useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54529/131

Comment: `Scaled` is no use, unfortunately. Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19479/131

Comment: you can of course divide `r` by `25.4` ..  Your CAD software has to have a provision to specify the default unit system to be used for interpretation though.

Answer (score 4):

With your information:

```
db=1;
aa=1.7;
r=db/2;
circle=ParametricPlot[r{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2Pi}][[1]];
inv={ParametricPlot[
r{(Sin[w]-wCos[w]),(Cos[w]+wSin[w])},{w,aa,0},
PlotStyle->{Thick,RGBColor[0.2,0.5,0.2]}][[1]]};

Graphics[{inv,circle},ImageSize->{450,400},Axes->True,
PlotRange->Automatic]
```

[image]

```
involute=Graphics[{inv,circle}]
```

[image]

I exported information to my desktop:

```
Export["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\output.dxf",involute]
```

I opened the DXF file in SolidWorks CAD software. The detail to care in `inch` is in software importing the file. Below is an image of the file being imported by SolidWorks software:

[image]

Check your CAD software for the data import unit that should be set to inches.

I made the measurement and I could verify that it was `one inch` or `25.4 milimeters`:

[image]