# Export::nodta: error on attempting to export a Graphics3D as an .STL file

Tags: export, graphics3d

```
Manipulate[Module[{},
  a1 = Map[Translate[{Scale[s1, 0.5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, 
    grow3 tetv];
  a2 = Map[
    Translate[{Scale[{{RGBColor[0.3, 1, 0.2], s1}, a1}, 
        0.5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, grow2 tetv];
  a3 = Map[
    Translate[{Scale[{{RGBColor[1, 0.3, 0.6], s1}, a2}, 
        0.5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, grow1 tetv];
  graphics3d = 
   Graphics3D[{s1, a3}, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
    ViewAngle -> 0.2, ViewPoint -> {-1.5, -4, 0.2}, ImageSize -> 470, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.56, 0.6}, {-0.3, 0.65}}]],
 {{grow1, 0.5, "stage 1"}, 0.17, 0.5, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{grow2, 0.5, "stage 2"}, 0.17, 0.5, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{grow3, 0.5, "stage 3"}, 0.17, 0.5, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 "",
 "show tetrahedron",
 {{tetgr, 0.3, ""}, 0.3, 1, ImageSize -> Tiny},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> {grow1, grow2, grow3, tetgr}, 
 Initialization :> (
   tv = N[1/(2 Sqrt[6])];
   oct = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Faces"];
   s1 = Scale[
     Rotate[Rotate[oct, Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}], ArcTan[Sqrt[2]], {0, 1, 0}],
      0.5 {1, 1, 1}];
   tet = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Faces"];
   tetv = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];)]

Export["graphics3d.stl", graphics3d]
```

> Export::nodta: Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the STL format.
>
> ```
> $Failed
> ```

What is a problem ?

Comment: This seems to be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19479/131. In short, `Scale` (perhaps `Translate` as well) does not work for `Export`ing STLs.

Answer (score 4):

`Scale` does work in strange ways. I think it is a design flaw that some transformations are only carried out during rendering (or that `Normal` works on `Translate`, but not on `Scale`). This makes geometric computations very awkward at times. Ah, well.

The following is a horrible frankenfix to make your example work. Essentially, you need to define your own transformation functions and use `Normal` to get proper coordinates from `Translate`:

```
scale[g_, scale_] := 
 g /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> scale*({x, y, z})

scale[g_, scale_, o_] := 
 g /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> scale*({x, y, z} - o)+o

Manipulate[
 Module[{}, 
  a1 = Map[Translate[{Scale[s1, 0.5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, 
    grow3 tetv];
  a2 = Map[
     Translate[{Scale[{{RGBColor[0.3, 1, 0.2], s1}, 
          a1}, .5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, grow2 tetv] // Normal;
  a3 = Map[
     Translate[{scale[{{RGBColor[1, 0.3, 0.6], s1}, 
          a2}, .5 {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]}, #] &, grow1 tetv] // Normal;
  graphics3d = 
   Graphics3D[{s1, a3}, Boxed -> False, SphericalRegion -> True, 
    ViewAngle -> 0.2, ViewPoint -> {-1.5, -4, 0.2}, ImageSize -> 470, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.56, 0.6}, {-0.3, 0.65}}]], {{grow1,
    0.5, "stage 1"}, 0.17, 0.5, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny}, {{grow2, 0.5, "stage 2"}, 0.17, 0.5, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny}, {{grow3, 0.5, "stage 3"}, 0.17, 0.5, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny}, "", "show tetrahedron", {{tetgr, 0.3, ""}, 0.3, 
  1, ImageSize -> Tiny}, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {grow1, grow2, grow3, tetgr}, 
 Initialization :> (tv = N[1/(2 Sqrt[6])];
   oct = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Faces"];
   s1 = scale[
     Rotate[Rotate[oct, Pi/4, {0, 0, 1}], 
       ArcTan[Sqrt[2]], {0, 1, 0}] // Normal, 0.5 {1, 1, 1}];
   tet = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Faces"];
   tetv = PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "VertexCoordinates"];)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The export seems to work fine now (as seen from Rhino3D). I chose `DXF` as format to get the colors across, but `STL` works as well, only without colors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]